# What happens when a player is fouled hard while they are going for an and one?

Tags: rules, basketball

Let's say Player A goes up for a layup and gets fouled while he's driving.

Now, once the foul has been called Defender B goes up to Player A and fouls him again (hard, so no mistake that it's a foul) and Player A misses the shot.

Can both the fouls be called or will there be a technical violation or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be considered dead ball contact and would result in a technical foul( or a flagrant foul if it was violent contact). Player A would get 2 free throws (1 if he made the layup) and then another 2 free throws for the dead ball foul.

[NBA Video Rulebook on dead ball contact.](http://videorulebook.nba.com/archive/technical-foul-dead-ball-contact-345/)

Comment: So this way, a player can get a five point play shooting a three?

Comment: Technically could result in up to a 6 point play. Made 3 pointer and 1 on the free throw and then 2 for the technical/flagrant.

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear, you cannot "go for an and one".  And one means you're getting the continuation, which is where you are in the middle of a shot, fouled, but the ball went into the basked in that shot you were in the middle of. At least in theory, if you're changing your action after the foul, it's not a continuation so it isn't an "and one" situation.  (In practice that may not always be the case, of course.)

So if a second player fouls you *while* you're doing that, odds are it's not a dead ball foul, but simply a foul, and you'll get one foul called (whichever they notice first or is worse) and one shot/pair of shots. That's assuming the second fouler initiated their play before the whistle (not *making* contact before the whistle, but starting the action that leads to the contact - jumping up, running full speed, whatever).

The player would have to initiate contact after the whistle (and probably a bit after the whistle, given reaction time) in order for it to count as a dead ball foul and get the technical free throws.

Comment: True, but im talking about cases where for example a blocking foul is called while a player is driving then another foul once he shoots a layup

Comment: If he "shoots" a layup then it's not a continuation.  If he finishes his layup, then it is, but the time there isn't much.  You're suggesting seconds in between the actions that aren't there in real play (if it's still legitimately a continuation).

Answer (score 2):

And 1's are only called on continuations / being in the act of shooting. Otherwise it's a dead ball non-shooting foul.

To my knowledge, you can't be called for "multiple regular fouls" on the same play.
You *can* be called for a flagrant on the original foul if you use excessive or unnecessary contact, OR if you late-hit them, which would usually result in a technical foul.
Or there are other situational fouls where someone's shot would count even if the foul was committed off-ball on a different teammate.