# In basketball, what would be the result of a foul on the shooter and then a foul on the player attempting to block the shot?

Tags: rules, basketball

Inspired a bit by [this question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/15716/what-happens-when-a-player-is-fouled-hard-while-they-are-going-for-an-and-one)...

The scenario:

- A player is fouled by a defender while in the act of shooting, and puts up a shot.
- Another defender sees the shot being taken, and has a path to block the shot on its upward trajectory.
- As he goes to block it, another offensive player steps late into the path of the defender, illegally impeding him.

What would the result be?

I'm assuming a player is legally allowed to block a shot after a whistle (when continuation is given... or also after the horn to end a quarter) since the shot is still live.

I'm also under the belief that typically an offensive player illegally impeding a defender's block would be a loose ball foul if the shot has already been released (an offensive foul before the ball is shot)?

Would the result be akin to a typical double foul?

Answer (score 2):

If the foul was called after the shooter was fouled, then this should lead to free throws for the shooter. This part is a given.

Getting to defensive player being impeded by another offensive player - Keep in mind that after the shooter is fouled, and the whistle is blown for that foul, there can be no "block" because the ball is dead (even if it's in the air). From this point on there can only be a goal tend (if the foul happened during continuation).

So basically your question is, *"If an offensive player is fouled after his teammate earns a shooting foul, can that foul be called?"*. Short answer. Absolutely. In basketball, a foul is a foul, whether it occurs during a dead ball or not.

Comment: In the NBA I am almost positive you can block a shot after the whistle so the fouled player does not get an easy and 1 on a layup

Comment: @Daffy yes but that is not recorded as a "block" on the stat sheet, else, w/ all the continuation in the NBA, we'd have a ton of players getting tons of blocked shots recorded.

Comment: that makes sense. I misread and thought you meant that the action of a block would automatically be considered a goaltend after a foul